# Firebase authentication: A network AuthError happening on new user flow

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

EDIT: See bottom of message for update on research about this issue.

Here is the code of firebase authentication in a vuejs app (localhost development for now). Upon successful user registration, when user is new, it is supposed to send a verification email to the user.

It does so randomly. And I can verify email when it does send it.
But it never reaches this line even when email is sent:

```
console.log( "Verification email sent" );
```

Because of this error that I see in console log:

> Error sending verification email:  FirebaseError: Firebase: A network
> AuthError (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable
> host) has occurred. (auth/network-request-failed).
> at z (assert.ts:136:55)
> at j (assert.ts:65:9)
> at ie (index.ts:205:5)
> at async Wt (email.ts:118:11)
> at async signInSuccessWithAuthResult (:5173/src/modules/account/Authentication.vue?t=1692809236937:26:11)

```
<script setup>
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import settings from "@/frontendSettings";
import { useAuthStore } from "@/modules/account/state/authStore";
import VerificationStatus from "@/modules/account/VerifiedEmailTracking.vue";


const authStore = useAuthStore();
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
const userInitialized = computed( () => authStore.authIsInitialized );
const verif = user ? user.emailVerified : "nouser";

var uiConfig = {
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async function ( authResult, redirectUrl ) {
      // User successfully signed in.
      if ( authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser ) {
        console.log( "New user status: ", authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser );
        // Send email verification
        try {
          await authResult.user.sendEmailVerification();
          console.log( "Verification email sent" );
          return true;
        } catch ( error ) {
          console.error( "Error sending verification email: ", error );
        }
      } else {
        console.log( "User is not new" );
        return true;
      }
    },
    uiShown: function () {
      // The widget is rendered.
      // Hide the loader.
      document.getElementById( "loader" ).style.display = "none";
    }
  },
  // Will use popup for IDP Providers sign-in flow instead of the default, redirect.
  signInFlow: "popup",
  signInSuccessUrl: `${settings.siteUrl}/account/loginsuccess`,
  signInOptions: [
    // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
    firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
  ],
  // Terms of service url.
  tosUrl: `${settings.siteUrl}/account`,
  // Privacy policy url.
  privacyPolicyUrl: `${settings.siteUrl}account`
};

let ui;

onMounted( () => {
  // This will ensure that the following code runs after the component is mounted to the DOM.
  ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance() || new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI( firebase.auth() );
  ui.start( "#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig );
} );
</script>

<template>


  <div v-show="!user && userInitialized">
    <h1>Authenticate</h1>
    <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
    <div id="loader">Loading...</div>

    <br/>
  </div>

  <div v-if="user && userInitialized">
    Currently logged in as : {{ user.displayName }}. Email: {{ user.email }}. Verified: {{ verif }}
  </div>
  <VerificationStatus/>

</template>
```

Is there a problem in my code or could there really be a network issue ?

EDIT:
It works when I use promise instead of async/await. But then return true; for redirect doesn't work so I must force a manual redirect:

```
signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function ( authResult, redirectUrl ) {
  // User successfully signed in.
  if ( authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser ) {
    console.log( "New user status: ", authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser );
    // Send email verification
    authResult.user.sendEmailVerification()
        .then( () => {
          console.log( "Verification email sent" );
          // return true; => Does not redirect to success url
          window.location.href = `${settings.siteUrl}/account/loginsuccess`;
          return false;
        } )
        .catch( error => {
          console.error( "Error sending verification email: ", error );
        } );
  } else {
    console.log( "Flow resumed" );
    return true;
  }
},
```

Still I would like to know why it doesn't work with async/await, and why return true; in the promise after email is sent doesn't redirect.